# Java String format with nested format not showing actual output

Tags: java, string

Why is this not working in Java whereas this works in C#?

```
String a = "Hello %s";
String b = "World";
String c = String.format("%s", a, b);

println c
```

Expected Output:

```
Hello World
```

Actual Output:

```
Hello %s
```

Comment: It wont work that way.

Comment: Java is not C#.

Comment: What about `String.format("%s %s", a, b);?
`

Comment: then logically it is wrong, there are %s 3 formats specified but populated only with values.

Comment: There is a difference between the `String` used in `String.format` and the `String` generated by the method. In the parameter, you only have one `%s`. This is logic since `String` are immutable. To be fair, it would be useful but that's not how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String#format` does not evaluate already resolved pattern to check if there are any tokens left. It takes substitute arguments and inserts it "as is" into required position specified in format. So what you did there is what you see on the output - first substitution is made. Since there are no more tokens in format, `b` is ignored.

However, format itself can be variable, so maybe you wanted to do this:

```
String a = "Hello %s";
String b = "World";
String c = String.format(a, b);
```

and this would give you `Hello World` in `c`

Answer (score 1):

You can format it like this

```
String a = "Hello %s";
String b = "World";
String c = String.format(a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at the java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) there is no implementation of `String#format` that requires a expression ("%s") to be specified. The correct usage for your use case would be `String.format("Hello %s", "World")`.

In your case `"%s"` will be replaced with the first parameter specified which happens to be `"Hello %s"`. Causing the output to be: "Hello %s".

Take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) java documentation page if you want to know more about all possible formats.

Comment: I don't get your point. What do you mean by "_there is no implementation of `String#format` that requires the pattern to be specified_". You just gave the documentation of `String.format` for a basic usage. I search but didn't find any mention of have a format a value so it would not really answer this problem.

Comment: As seen in the example of this question the user is specifying the pattern with `String.format("%s", a, b);`. This might be confusing because `"Hello %s"` could be seen as the pattern but `"%s"` can also be seen as pattern. But a better word for `"%s"` would be expression. And I'm not completely getting your point why my answer is not correct.

Comment: Because it doesn't explain why the "expression" present in a value is not seen as an expression itself. You only provide link (which is not really correct based on [answer]) explaining the basic usage but I never found anywhere a mention of an expression in a value so this is not answer the problem of OP but just explain how to use `String.format`. This is why your answer, for me, is not complete.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I agree with you and will update my answer.